# How is term frequency calculated in scikit-learn CountVectorizer

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I do not understand how CountVectorizer calculates the term frequency. I need to know this so that I can make a sensible choice for the `max_df` parameter when filtering out terms from a corpus. Here is example code:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

    vectorizer = CountVectorizer(min_df = 1, max_df = 0.9)
    X = vectorizer.fit_transform(['afr bdf dssd','afr bdf c','afr'])
    word_freq_df = pd.DataFrame({'term': vectorizer.get_feature_names(), 'occurrences':np.asarray(X.sum(axis=0)).ravel().tolist()})
    word_freq_df['frequency'] = word_freq_df['occurrences']/np.sum(word_freq_df['occurrences'])
    print word_freq_df.sort('occurrences',ascending = False).head()

       occurrences  term  frequency
    0            3   afr   0.500000
    1            2   bdf   0.333333
    2            1  dssd   0.166667
```

It seems that 'afr' appears in half of the terms in my corpus, as I expect by looking at the corpus. However, when I set `max_df  = 0.8` in `CountVectorizer`, the term 'afr' is filtered out of my corpus. Playing around, I find that with the coprus in my example, CountVectorizer assigns a frequency of ~0.833 to 'afr'. Could someone provide a formula on how the term frequency which enterts `max_df` is calculated?

Thanks

Comment: I have given an answer below.  However, I don't understand what your DataFrame there is showing.  "afr" occurs in *all* the documents of your corpus and thus would have a proportional document frequency of 1.  Your `frequency` column is computing the number of documents a given term is in divided by the total document-frequency of all terms, which I don't think is very meaningful.  You should be dividing by the number of documents in your corpus, not the sum of all frequencies.

Comment: Thanks! I think it was a misunderstanding on my part of what  'frequency' means. I will call it something different (density?), but I think what I calculate is the quantity I want. I want this quantity to be proportional to number of occurrences of a term in the corpus, and to sum to one. It seems to be the most sensible choice for plotting the variation of how popular a term is for different documents in my corpus. But maybe it's getting late -will think about it tomorrow...

Comment: Ok, after getting some sleep, what I called `frequency` above is the probability that I pick a given term if I pick randomly out of my corpus. The utility of this is to get an idea of how popular a term is across different corpora (i.e. with what probability it occurs in each corpus), regardless of the size of each individual corpus. The underlying property is that in my corpora (a collection of article titles) each term which is not a stopword appears at most once in each document. I hope this clarifies it more.

Comment: Okay, so it's the relative frequency.  But I don't think this really has much to do with your question.  Even if what you want is the relative frequency, you can't filter by it.  `max_df` only filters by *document* frequency --- the number (or proportion) of documents that the term is in.  If you want to filter by relative word frequency, you'll have to do it yourself in a separate step after vectorizing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is apparently not with how the frequency is calculated, but with how the `max_df` threshold is applied.  The code for `CountVectorizer` does this:

```
max_doc_count = (max_df
    if isinstance(max_df, numbers.Integral)
    else int(round(max_df * n_doc))
)
```

That is, the maximum document count is obtained by *rounding* the document proportion times the number of documents.  This means that, in a 3-document corpus, any `max_df` threshold which equates to more than 2.5 documents actually counts the same as a threshold of 3 documents.  You are seeing a "frequency" of 2.5/3=0.8333 --- that is, a term that occurs in ~83.3% of 3 documents occurs in 2.5 of them, which is rounded up to 3, meaning it occurs in all of them.

In short, "afr" is correctly considered to have a document frequency of 3, but the maximum document frequency is incorrectly considered to be 3 (0.9*3=2.7, rounded up to 3).

I would consider this a bug in scikit.  A maximum document frequency should round *down*, not up.  If the threshold is 0.9, a term which occurs in all documents exceeds the threshold and should be excluded.